# i want to locate pageview in listview

Tags: flutter, android-studio

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.purpleAccent.shade200,
        title: Text_Button(),
        actions: [IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.menu))],
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children:[ PageView(
          children: [
            Image.asset(
              "asset/img/1.PNG",
            ),
            Image.asset(
              "asset/img/2.PNG",
            ),
          ],
        )],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I don't know why it does no work.
I think maybe the problem from the relationship between ListView and Pageview
or my image.
i want to upload the error name but the code is too long to upload.
please help me
the ultimate my purpose is it.
it : locate my images on the top of my app under the appbar with pageview function.

The reason I want to use a list view is because my app is vertically long, so it doesn't fit on the screen all at once. at the same time
as a pageview under the app bar
I want to add slideable photos. How the hell can I do that? Because I am Korean, my English is poor. Please understand. handsome friends.

few days ago
in the column
with pageview
put textbutton
I have a memory.
So I know that a Pageview can be put inside a Colmn.
therefore
Put Pageview in Colmn,
I tried to align upwards with mainaxis but this also
error pops up
So I thought about it, a few days ago
I used a long photo vertically, but this time I used a long photo horizontally.
Perhaps this is the problem.

Comment: can you share your UI or code?
without knowing UI perspective it is tough to give solution or suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [carousel_slider: ^4.2.1](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider)  package to set slidable photos under appbar